# iCloud Drive upload / download battle

Tags: icloud

I have encountered an issue with the latest version of macOS Sonoma, to which I updated a few days ago.

I rely heavily on a specific folder on my iCloud Drive, and I need it to be constantly indexed and readily available offline. However, since updating, this folder is consistently being uploaded back to the cloud.

The problem unfolds like this: I download the folder, use its contents for a few hours, and then observe iCloud actively uploading the files back to the cloud, seemingly excluding them from local indexing. This forces me to download the folder once again, only to have the same cycle repeat itself. This is frustrating since a substantial portion of my working day is spent without internet access.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue, and is there a way to force iCloud Drive to always keep this specific folder available offline?

I'm looking for guidance or possible solutions to resolve this problem. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Thank you!